# Unable to show Snacker from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-snackbar

I'm working with an adapter that handles its own service call to update its items (not my adapter).  This adapter defines an interface I can pass in to make callbacks to views to show/hide loading indicators.  I want to show a Snacker when a call fails (example: no network connection).  I've defined that method in the interface and added it to my `Fragment`, and I've updated the adapter to call that method when a service call fails.

```
@Override
public void OnLoaded(int count) {
}

@Override
public void OnStartLoading() {
    showRefresh();
}

@Override
public void OnStopLoading() {
    clearRefresh();
}

@Override
public void OnServiceFailure() {
    showSnackBar(getString(R.string.error));
}

protected void showSnackBar(String message) {
    View view = getView();
    if (view != null && getUserVisibleHint()) {
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.accent_dark));
        snackbar.setAction(getString(R.string.retry), v -> {
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                onRefresh();
                });
        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the Snackbar doesn't show.

Here's the thing:  `OnServiceFailure()` is being called from a thread.  I've tried wrapping the call to `showSnackBar()` in `activity.runOnUiThread()`, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.  I've also debugged `showSnackBar()` and it *IS* finding `view` and `view` *IS* the root `FrameLayout`.

If I call `showSnackBar()` anywhere else from the main thread, everything works fine.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: did you call also a Runnable?

Comment: @trocchietto I have also tried `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> showSnackBar(getString(R.string.error_requesting_tweets)));`

Comment: Apparently, if I do `new Handler().post(() -> showSnackBar(getString(R.string.error_requesting_tweets)));` *inside* `runOnUiThread()`, it works.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When using an service or thread you can only show a snackbar on the main (UI) thread. for fragments there is a special function inside the view object to post your code to the main thread.

```
View view = getView();    
view.post()
```

this send your code to the main thread and shows the SnackBar.